# How can I get an HtmlElementCollection from webview2

Tags: webview2, htmlelements

My old WinForm application used HtmlElementCollection to process a page

```
        HtmlDocument doc = Browser.Document;
        HtmlElementCollection elems = doc.GetElementsByTagName("table");
        HtmlElement a = elems[0];
        int[] Hucrn = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, };
        HtmlElementCollection satirlar = a.GetElementsByTagName("tr");
```

ı want to use webview2. But I am not getting htmlelementcollection.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: You have to access the DOM with javascript, you can't directly access it from C#. Here's a link to get you started: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms#step-11---scripting

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to using JavaScript to interact with the DOM you can install [WebView2.DevTools.Dom](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebView2.DevTools.Dom/) from Nuget.org. It's free for anyone to use. Project on [GitHub](https://github.com/ChromiumDotNet/WebView2.DevTools.Dom).

Your code would look something like:

```cs
await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
 
 // Create one instance per CoreWebView2
 // Reuse devToolsContext if possible, dispose (via DisposeAsync) before creating new instance
 // Make sure to call DisposeAsync when finished or await using as per this example
// Add using WebView2.DevTools.Dom; to access the CreateDevToolsContextAsync extension method
await using var devToolsContext = await webView2Browser.CoreWebView2.CreateDevToolsContextAsync();

//Get all table elements
var tableElements = await devtoolsContext.QuerySelectorAllAsync<HtmlTableElement>("table");

var table = tableElements[0];

var body = await table.GetBodyAsync();
var rows = await body.GetRowsAsync().ToArrayAsync();

foreach (var row in rows)
{
    var cells = await row.GetCellsAsync().ToArrayAsync();

    foreach (var cell in cells)
    {
        await table.SetInnerHtmlAsync("Updated Div innerText");
    }
}

//Alternatively Get a reference to the HtmlCollection and use async enumerable
//Requires Net Core 3.1 or higher
var tableRowsHtmlCollection = await table.GetRowsAsync();

await foreach (var row in tableRowsHtmlCollection)
{
    var cells = await row.GetCellsAsync();
    await foreach (var cell in cells)
    {
        var newDiv = await devToolsContext.CreateHtmlElementAsync<HtmlDivElement>("div");
        await newDiv.SetInnerTextAsync("New Div Added!");
        await cell.AppendChildAsync(newDiv);
    }
}


//Alternatively use querySelector syntax to directly return all cells within a table
//https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#examples
//Get all table elements
var tableCells = await devtoolsContext.QuerySelectorAllAsync<HtmlTableCellElement>("table td");

foreach (var cell in tableCells)
{
    await table.SetInnerHtmlAsync("Updated Div innerText");
}
```

More details and examples in the [Readme](https://github.com/ChromiumDotNet/WebView2.DevTools.Dom#webview2-devtools-dom). I'm working on a guide for those porting from the old `IE WebBrowser` which is at https://github.com/ChromiumDotNet/WebView2.DevTools.Dom/discussions/3

Comment: I've just released version 2.0.2 which has improved table support, example has been updated.

Comment: Version 3.0 adds support for async enumerable