VB.NET Webbrowser to WebView2
Can someone help?  This code works perfectly in setting the values on a website using the older webbrowser in VB.NET.  I am attempting to move to the WebView2 and cannot figure out the magic Javascript to make it work.  Can someone please help?  Thank you in advance.
NOTE: records_array(z)(4) and others are just dates in an array, in this format "06/01/2024"
Dim inputs As HtmlElementCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")

For Each input As HtmlElement In inputs

    If Not IsNothing(input) Then

        If input.GetAttribute("data-ig") = "x:939876968.0:mkr:3" Then

            input.InvokeMember("focus")
            input.SetAttribute("value", format_CHD_date(records_array(z)(6)))
            add_to_log(log_window, "Passing Admit Date value to site = " & format_CHD_date(records_array(z)(6)))
            Application.DoEvents()

        End If

        If input.GetAttribute("data-ig") = "x:136274528.0:mkr:3" Then

            input.InvokeMember("focus")
            input.SetAttribute("value", format_CHD_date(records_array(z)(7)))
            add_to_log(log_window, "Passing Discharge Date value to site = " & format_CHD_date(records_array(z)(7)))
            Application.DoEvents()

        End If

        If input.GetAttribute("data-ig") = "x:101172535.0:mkr:3" Then

            input.InvokeMember("focus")
            input.SetAttribute("value", format_CHD_date(records_array(z)(4)))
            add_to_log(log_window, "Passing DOB value to site = " & format_CHD_date(records_array(z)(4)))
            Application.DoEvents()

        End If

    End If

Next



This code works for another element on the same page:
Await WebView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('ctl00_MainBody_ctl00_lastTextBox').invoke;")
Await WebView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('ctl00_MainBody_ctl00_lastTextBox').setAttribute('value', '" & records_array(int_next)(2) & "');")

This is all of what I have tried that has not sent the value to the element giving me issues:
Await WebView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelector('[data-ig='x:939876968.0:mkr:3']').focus();")
Await WebView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelector('[data-ig='x:939876968.0:mkr:3']').value = '01/15/2024';")

Await WebView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelector('[data-ig='x:939876968.0:mkr:3']').focus();")
Await WebView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelector('[data-ig='x:939876968.0:mkr:3']').setAttribute('value', '01/15/2024');")

Await WebView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelector('[data-ig='x:939876968.0:mkr:3']').invoke();")
Await WebView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelector('[data-ig='x:939876968.0:mkr:3']').value = '01/15/2024';")

Await WebView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelector('[data-ig='x:939876968.0:mkr:3']').invoke();")
Await WebView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelector('[data-ig='x:939876968.0:mkr:3']').setAttribute('value', '01/15/2024');")


The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73846538/10024425, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65470588/10024425, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/68592056/10024425. There all posts that I've written. Start with the first one in the list - it should be the newest one. Take what you can from it, then get what you need from one (or both) of the other posts.

Thank you for getting back to me.  Your demo was how I was able to start my project.  I am able to set the values on standard input elements using javascript.  The challenge I face with these particular elements is that they do not have an id or tag. They have an attribute of "data-ig".  I cannot figure out how to utilize that attribute to find the element to set the value.  Does that make sense?

I have tried this but still its not updating the element on the page.
codeAwait WebView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelector('[data-ig='x:939876968.0:mkr:3']').value = '" & records_array(int_next)(4) &"';") code

You may consider adding a HTML example to your post. I'm fairly certain that this is covered in this post (which is the second on in the list above) - the code under the heading TestButtonClick.js (Option 2).  Something you may need to add to the code can be found here: Element: getAttribute() method

I added images of the date controls and the markup.  Odd that there is no value attribute, but when I set the value in VB using the webbrowser it worked correctly.
I am so lost...  any other suggestions?

Where does your code fail? Are the inputs selected and do you enter the loop? Are the attributes successfully queried and do your  if statements evaluate as expected? Are there any errors?

The code doesnt fail, it just never sets the date value in the input boxes when using the WebView2, but it works fine in the WebBrowser.

Your code fails in that it doesn't do what you expect. The important questions is where? Selecting based on GetElementsByTagName? Pulling the attribute value? Comparing the value? Updating the value? There are several potential points of failure in your code. It would be helpful to narrow those down.

Also worth a look : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71760798/4665

If you'd like assistance with your code that uses WebView2, then you'll have to post it.

Ive edited to original post to include what I have tried, and what has worked passing values to other elements on the same page.

That code isn't even close to the code in the post that I referenced above and will never work as desired. The referenced posts were written to be very detailed for a reason. I recommend that you set your project aside temporarily. Then re-create the project in the post following the steps exactly (including the programming language). Once you have that working, re-create the project in the post, writing it in VB.NET. Once you've successfully done that, you should have acquired the experience necessary to achieve your goal.

I did create your project.  That's how I got started ...  as I have stated, my code works on some input elements, meaning setting the values works, but it does not work on other input elements.  The difference?  The problem input elements values are dates...

All those statements are unlikely to work. Most likely there should only be one ExecuteScriptAsync statement which means that you should have created a JavaScript function as shown in the post (see TestButtonClick.js (Option 2)).

I will try that and see if I can get it to work.  Thank you for your continued assistance.

Given your problematic fields are dates, have you checked your dates are formatted as expected by input type=date , ie yyyy-mm-dd

The site input type is text...  I think it might be the control used by the site itself that is causing my issue.  Still digging.  Thank you for your reply.

Check the docs for those date controls well. Some older ones needed to be set via javascript, simply adding the value attribute did does not work. Particularly if added after the DOM has loaded and whatever the initialization code for those controls has run. What library or control are being used for the date pickers?

I am not sure how the input element is created. It looks like it is missing a "/" when closing the input element. It should look like the code below.
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10" />


I have no control over the site I am attempting to set the values on.  Its a task I am assigned to at work to fill in data, click a button, and retrieve the returned data.  For lack of a better term, scraping...

The / is optional and is only recommended to be used with caution : https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags
